# Can someone give me a basic parts list of required items for .net micro framework development?

Tags: .net-micro-framework

assuming I have already purchased a .net mf board such as a tahoe II, what other items are required?

Obviously sensors will vary on the projects I'm doing, but what stuff will I need for every project?

Edit: Okay so maybe I got excited and didn't provide enough detail. Assuming I have a board such as the Tahoe 2 and a computer and a cable to hook it up and copy programs across. What other items do I need (examples circuit boards, transistors, soldering iron, etc) what are the required items that each project is likely to need.

Update:
**Basic Hardware Parts list**
•Leds
•Resistors
•Caps
•Transistors
•Solderless breadboard
•Solid core wire
•Crocodile clamps
•External power supply (5V for Meridan boards)
•Multimeter
•Some sensors
•Network Cable

GPIO, I2C,SPI and UART all supported.

**Software**
Visual Studio 2010 (express or a retail edition)

Comment: Basic things: power supply, programmer?

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood Thomas O. I believe is he talking about a device that will actually program the board.

Comment: my understanding is that boards such as tahoe can be hooked up to a PC and have a .net mf application copied across. I'm familiar with C# so this is the approach I'd like to take. I'll edit the question to try to be more specfic. Apologies to Thomas O.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as 'required items'. You can stock up on some basic parts, however. You're very likely to need:

- Leds
- Resistors
- Caps
- Transistors
- Solderless breadboard
- Solid core wire
- Crocodile clamps
- External power supply (5-12V?)
- Multimeter
- Some sensors
- ...

And if you're planning to actually build something: there are loads of questions about soldering irons/solder/... on this site; check those out.

Comment: I think your answer may be more directed to someone using an Arduino. "Shields" is just a concept used by Arduino. He is using a board for semi-embedded .Net development.

Comment: Ah you're right, I could've sworn I read 'netduino' somewhere :-) I removed that bit.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have decided to go with a development platform that is all inclusive the number of require components will be rather small.

On the software side, I believe you will need Visual Studio.

On the hardware side, this will depend mostly on what sensors you will want to integrate with and through what interface. In almost all circumstances I would suggest getting "Expansion connectors that expose GPIO, I2C, SPI and UART signals"
These are different protocols that you will be using to interface with your sensors.

Comment: Also, when you go to pick out what sensors you are using, look for those protocol types as sticking to them will make your life easy.

Comment: Should I preference GPIO over say I2C or UART, or is it more a case of just using whatever is available with that sensor type?

Comment: This somewhat depends on what you are wanting to do. Is just general purpose IO, these don't usually have a huge use in sensor networks. I suspect you will be using SPI/I2C and UART more often then just general IO. I also would guess that you will use the 2 ADC inputs.